# Laravel range filter in decimal numbers

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to filter products table with column that contains decimal numbers like 1.423. I am want to filter numbers in range like between from 1.243 to 1.742. In database I have tried making column as float, integer and varchar. But it's not working.

This is my controller:

```
$products = Product::where('state_id', '=', '1')
                    ->when(!empty($minthick), function ($query) use ($minthick) {
                        return $query->where('thick', '>=', $minthick);
                    })
                    ->when(!empty($maxthick), function ($query) use ($maxthick) {
                        return $query->where('thick', '<=', $maxthick);
                    })
                    ->when(!empty($minwidth), function ($query) use ($minwidth) {
                        return $query->where('width', '>=', $minwidth);
                    })
                    ->when(!empty($maxwidth), function ($query) use ($maxwidth) {
                        return $query->where('width', '<=', $maxwidth);
                    })
                    ->when(!empty($minweight), function ($query) use ($minweight) {
                        return $query->where('weight', '>=', $minweight);
                    })
                    ->when(!empty($maxweight), function ($query) use ($maxweight) {
                        return $query->where('weight', '<=', $maxweight);
                    })
                    ->get();
```

All filters should work individually. I don't understand where I'm making mistake. I have another filter that contains category which is working fine. Here's Html:

```
<th scope="col"><!-- Thickness -->
              <label>Thickness:</label>
              <div class="form-row mx-0">
                <div>
                  <select class="form-control" name="minthick">
                    <option value="">Min</option>
                    @forelse ($thick as $th)
                        <option value="{{$th}}">{{ $th }}</option>
                    @empty
                        <p>No filter availvale</p>
                    @endforelse
                  </select>
                </div> -- 
                <div>
                  <select class="form-control" name="maxthick">
                    <option value="">Max</option>
                    @forelse ($thick as $th)
                        <option value="{{$th}}">{{ $th }}</option>
                    @empty
                        <p>No filter availvale</p>
                    @endforelse
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
              <label>Width</label>
              <div class="form-row mx-0">
                <div class="">
                  <select class="form-control" name="minwidth">
                    <option value="">Min</option>
                    @forelse ($width as $wi)
                        <option value="{{$wi}}">{{ $wi }}</option>
                    @empty
                        <p>No filter availvale</p>
                    @endforelse
                  </select>
                </div> -- 
                <div class="">
                  <select class="form-control" name="maxwidth">
                    <option value="">Max</option>
                    @forelse ($width as $wi)
                        <option value="{{$wi}}">{{ $wi }}</option>
                    @empty
                        <p>No filter availvale</p>
                    @endforelse
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col"><!-- Weight -->
              <label>Weight:</label>
              <div class="row form-row">
                <div>
                  <select class="form-control" name="minweight">
                    <option value="">Min</option>
                    @forelse ($weight as $we)
                        <option value="{{$we}}">{{ $we }}</option>
                    @empty
                        <p>No filter availvale</p>
                    @endforelse
                  </select>
                </div> -- 
                <div>
                  <select class="form-control p-0" name="maxweight">
                    <option value="">Max</option>
                    @forelse ($weight as $we)
                        <option value="{{$we}}">{{ $we }}</option>
                    @empty
                        <p>No filter availvale</p>
                    @endforelse
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Laravel `whereBetween()` like so

```
Product::where('state_id', '=', '1')
         ->whereBetween('thick', [$minthick, $maxthick])
         ->whereBetween('width', [$minwidth, $maxwidth])
         ->whereBetween('weight', [$minweight, $maxweight])
         ->get();
```